# How to sync Xero Journals since X date?

Tags: xero-api

Trying sync all Journal Info for last 3 years ago, starting at period 1.  Sync all is easy by journal number order, but if you have a data file with 10 years of data,  how to skip the 7 years before the target date (eg period 1 year 2020).   It seems you can get since modified, but thats not the same.  Many would have a modified date before the transaction date.  Indeed at the end of the day this info has to reconcilte with the trail balance so any missed transaction will but the figures out.

I could get since last modified at x date, subtract 100 from journal number and sync in Journal number order from then on.  BUT I can still see problems

I have read all in Sequential Date order.  And tried the modified date, but as stated in question thats no good.